# Invariant Violation even after export

Tags: react-native

Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or function but got: undefined.

I have already looked around for a solution but could found one. Common causes of this problem are not exporting classes, but I have done that.

Check the render methode of EntryListScreen:

```
    import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {
        View,
        ListView,
        Icon,
        Text
      } from 'react-native';


    import EntryList from './EntryList';

    class EntryListScreen extends React.Component{
    render(){
                var stateSticky = this.fetchParam("sticky");
                var stateCategory = this.fetchParam('category', 'all');
                return(
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection:'column'}}>   
                {/*<Text>[DEBUG EntryListScreen] Category: {stateCategory} Sticky: {stateSticky}</Text>*/}
                <EntryList propCategory={stateCategory} propSticky={stateSticky}  style={{flex:1}}/>
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <Icon
                        onPress={() => Alert.alert('Vote Down','Noch nicht verfügbar')}
                        name="call-received"
                        color="white"
                        />
                </View>
                </View>
                );
            }
       }

export default withNavigation(EntryListScreen);
```

If I replace the icon with a button it works fine:

```
<Button
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Search')}
            title="Suchen"
            color="#a74f13"
        />
```

I have this bug in other parts of my app as well and can't find the root of the cause.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {
        Icon,
        SearchBar
      } from 'react-native'
```

Don NOT import them from react-native they are seperated.

```
  import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements'
```

or

```
  import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
```